# Python statsmodel ARMA question

Tags: python, arima

I am reading through the documentation of statsmodel package in python from the [link](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA)

> The (p,q) order of the model for the number of AR parameters, differences, and MA parameters to use.

How do I specify the order for ARMA(2,5); ARIMA(2,1,4), AR(2) and MA(6)? I am not able to figure from the document explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ARIMA(2,1,4)` you would need to use the ARIMA model, [as described here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.html).

You would call with something like this

```
ARIMA(endog, order = (2, 1, 4))
```

where `endog` is your endogenous variable and the tuple given for `order` follows the convention AR, Differencing, MA.

For `ARMA(1, 1)` you could just use `ARMA(endog, order = (1, 1))`.